# How could I customize the datatable with custom text and remove footer

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to customize the datatable,

here's the current JS code,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#flight_prices').DataTable({"bPaginate": false, "bFilter": true});
  } );
```

[image]

Comment: These are all configurable if you read the docs

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not sure what you mean by 'placeholder', whatever you put in the search text box will filter the table.

```
$('#flight_prices').DataTable({        
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": "data"},          
    "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "New text: "},
    "bPaginate": false
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8xo9n63b/2/).

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the following code:

```
$('#flight_prices').DataTable({
   "language": {
       "search": "Custom text: ",
       "searchPlaceholder": "Type text here"
   },
   "paging": false,
   "info": false
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk41wLwu/) fore code and demonstration.